# How can I execute casperjs from php?

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a test.js code from manual http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed args:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);

casper.exit();
```

and I can successfully execute it from the terminal '$ casperjs test.js arg1 arg2 arg3 --foo=bar --plop anotherarg'. It's working and this is good, but I need to execute this from the PHP script, I have tried to do it by PHP code:

```
<?php

function parser() {
    try {
        echo(exec("C:\casperjs\bin\casperjs.exe  C:\OpenServer\domains\casper\test.js arg1 arg2 arg3 --foo=bar --plop anotherarg"));
        flush();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo('error!');
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}

parser();

putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");

?>
```

But I have got a failure 'phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:110 in __die'. 
How can I do it properly? Please help!

Comment: Try [this lib](https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs), its working for me. You can also extend and hack it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use a PHP wrapper for CasperJS:

- [php-casperjs](https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs)
- [casperjs-php](https://github.com/synackSA/casperjs-php) (an extension of the above library)

Alternatively, you can use [`exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to execute a command:

```
$result = exec('PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs script.js');
echo $result;
```